# Laravel - Update another attribute when updating model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In one of my models I need to update another attribute when two other attributes from the same model are updated.

In my case, using an `Accessor` is not an option, because in some cases I will need to do a database query looking for `full_phone_number`.

What is the best to achive the desired result?

This is my model:

```php
class Address extends Model {
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'country_code',
        'phone_number',
        'full_phone_number',
    ];
    
}
```

When I create a new `Address`, I need the `full_phone_number` column to be automatically populated:

```php
$address = Address::create([
    'country_code' => 55,
    'phone_number' => 1199999999
]);
```

The expected result is:

```json
# Address model on DB
{
    "country_code": 55,
    "phone_number": 1199999999,
    "full_phone_number": 551199999999
}
```

When I update `country_code` or `phone_number` from an `Address`, I need the `full_phone_number` column to be automatically updated:

```php
$address->update([
    'phone_number' => 1188888888
]);
```

The expected result is:

```json
# Address model on DB
{
    "country_code": 55,
    "phone_number": 1188888888,
    "full_phone_number": 551188888888
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the desired result using `events`, but I don't know if this is the best way to handle this case. The same could be converted to an `observer`.

```php
class Address extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'country_code',
        'phone_number',
        'full_phone_number',
    ];
    
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::updating(function ($address) {
            $address->full_phone_number = $address->country_code . $address->number;
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the full_phone_number? Obviously you have it working here and thats fine. But could you not concatenate them together on the controller or template level?

Comment: @Bossman My API works with several events coming from outside using webhooks, many changes are made all the time. Until now we performed searches using only `country_code` and `phone_number`, now we will have the need to do queries using the two columns concatenated. As our database is large and has too many queries per second I don't want to create a `view` to use the `full_phone_number` so as not to overload it.